# spring boot intellij jsp navigate and auto complete not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I have Developed an Spring Boot Application and it works without any problem.
But I have some issues in Intellij:
first: Auto Complete does not working in my JSP files and Java Classes are not recognized in my JSP files (I Blindly code in JSP files)
second: It is not possible to click on jsp file name in Controller class and Navigate to the JSP file.

for example : return(index); >>> index is not clickable so it is not possible to navigate to jsp files in editor...I should Manually find JSP files.

How Can I resolve These problems Taking into Consideration when I build and run project with Maven it works without any problem. But Mentioned problems Bother me during writing code in intellij.

Comment: Don't "blindly code in JSP files", then--take advantage of the clean decoupling Spring MVC gives you between logic and presentation.

Comment: Why Auto Complete not working in JSP files (Intellij Spring boot)

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206925265-how-to-get-syntax-highlighting-for-jsp-files-in-intellij-

Comment: @jmw5598 thanks for the link I checked It....Java EE plugin is enabled but my problem has not been solved yet.

Comment: I am still waiting for solution...Can anyone help?

Comment: No answer yet? Is it possible? Maybe it's not?